# Cant get tasklist batch file to output substring

Tags: windows, batch-file, substring, findstr, tasklist

Not really a batch file user (more of a python guy here) wanting to get an output to just show the video title in a MS Edge YouTube tab (ultimately into a txt file, but I am going one step at a time and don't wanna waste too much of peoples time asking things on here. But I hit like 5 hours of debugging and searching how substrings work)

The batch I have made for testing is

```
@ECHO OFF
SET LIST=tasklist /fi "imagename eq msedge.exe" /fo list /v 
SET TITLE=%LIST%|findstr YouTube
SET OUTPUT=%TITLE:~14,-39%
ECHO %OUTPUT%
```

gives

```
~14,-39%
```

---

For a reference example

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq msedge.exe" /fo list /v | findstr YouTube
```

in cmd the prompt gives me

```
Window Title: Skyline Drive & The Polaris Airship - Sunrise Over Sterling [Silk Music] - YouTube - Personal - Microsoft? Edge
```

But if someone knows how to grab the Windows 10 music toast notification area and plop it into a text file instead of having to use the WINDOWTITLE part of tasklist, that would be amazing. Even in like Node.js, Python, or really anything low intensity I can launch in Win 10.

Comment: You aren't actually doing anything . See `for /?`.

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq msedge.exe" /fo list /v ^| findstr YouTube') do set "title=%%a"`

Comment: Thank you, I just needed to add ```echo %title:~14,-39% >> /Desktop/title.txt``` and that works! How do I give you the answer point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In batch `set variable=command` doesn't work. It assigns the literal string to the variable, not the output of the command. To do that, you need a `for /f` loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq msedge.exe" /fo list /v ^| findstr YouTube') do set "title=%%a"
echo %title:~14,-39% >> /Desktop/title.txt
```

Usually, you can define which part of the output you return with proper `tokens` and `delims` (see `for /?`), but in this case, it's better to get the whole line and post-process it, as the tokens differ in different languages (English: `Window title` (two tokens), German: `Fenstertitel` (one token))